# How to capture the label name?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Could you please help me in capturing the text or label name of the below mentioned code:

```
<td class="labelCol last">
<label for="CF00N20000003eIaC">Gifts & Entertainment Expenditure</label>
</td>
```

Regards,
Sambit

Comment: What language? What text are you trying to get? The `Gifts & Entertainment Expenditure`?

Comment: Yes I am using java and yes I need to capture Gifts & Entertainment Expenditure.. Kindly advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='CF00N20000003eIaC']")).getText();
```

Or, if "CF00N20000003eIaC" is dynamic,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@class='last']//label")).getText();
```

Comment: @user1834699 The way you say "thanks" on StackOverflow is by accepting the best answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using the information you gave us, try

```
String labelText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.last label")).getText();
```

This selects the label based on the `last` class of the `<td>`. If there are more of those elements on the page, it won't work. If there are more `label` elements in the `td`, it won't work.

You either have to provide us with more page context, or you should be able to come up with a better selector based on the page context.